# Web service not showing after Azure successful release/deploy

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration

I have an Angular project that I want to deploy automatically by using Azure DevOps CI/CD. Everything works fine, even the deployment "works" successfully. But if I navigate to the Azure app service URL, I don't see the app.

[image: This is the build yml file]

Comment: Kindly confirm if the web.config is available in your app. You can either add a web.config file to your source or auto-generate one using the File Transforms and Variable Substitution Options of the task > Click on the task and go to Generate web.config parameters.



To access the Application Event Log, use the Diagnose and solve problems blade in the Azure portal. 
1. In the Azure portal, open the app in App Services.
2. Select Diagnose and solve problems.

Comment: @M Yil Did you followed the suggestions in above comments. How did it go? You can also visit https://{site name}.scm.azurewebsites.net to check the deployed files in your web service server.

Comment: I've voted to close this as needing a [mcve] because the YAML config is rendered as an image.